# Open URL from API when Button is Pressed in Custom TableViewCell

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, uitableview

I want to click a button in a custom xib file and it goes to a link passed in through an api using decodable.

I am able to make the entire row redirect to a link from the api by using:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let item = page!.tradeshows[indexPath.row]

    if let eventURLS = item.url {

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(eventURLS, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {print("link not working")
  }
}
```

But I don't want to select the entire row, I only want to select the button from the custom .xib file.

I also tried:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) - > UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell",
        for: indexPath) as!EventTableViewCell
    let item = page!.tradeshows[indexPath.row]

    cell.registerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UpcomingEventsViewController.onClickedRegistrationButton(_: )),
        for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.registerButton.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}

@objc func onClickedRegistrationButton(_ button: UIButton) {
    let buttonLink = button.tag
}
```

but I'm not sure how to set the link from the json data so that the indexPath is correct using this second approach.

Comment: start property names with small letter `tableData`

Comment: it's better to update your project to latest swift , swift 2 can't be uploaded to store now

Comment: also you have 2 arrays `page!.tradeshows` and `tableData ` decide which 1 is the table data source to correctly access inside `onClickedRegistrationButton`

Comment: I updated the first code snippet so it's an example from my actual project. Before it was just similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the action is not directly related to the view controller it's more efficient to pass the URL to the cell and open the URL there. The target / action code is not needed.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell", for: indexPath) as! EventTableViewCell
    let item = page!.tradeshows[indexPath.row]
    cell.url = item.url
    return cell
}
```

In the cell add a property `url` and an `IBAction` for the button

```
class EventTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

    var url : URL!

    // other properties

    @IBAction func pushButton(_ sender : UIButton) {
       UIApplication.shared.open(url) 
    }

    // other code
}
```

Side note:

Your first snippet is Swift 2 code. The method will never be called in Swift 3+

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
@objc func onClickedRegistrationButton(_ button: UIButton) {  
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:tableData[button.tag])!) 
}
```